# How can we pass value from js to modal

Tags: jsp

JSP:

```
 <td style="width:630px;"><button class="btn btn-info" onclick="sample1('<%=reachibility%>')">Check Run Status</button></td>
```

JavaScript:

```
function sample(runstatus){
    var a=runstatus;

    $("#status").modal("show");
}


 <div id="status" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Run Status</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div id="errorMessage">

                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">

                            <label>Status:</label>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">

                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
```

I have a string in `runstatus` and I need to display in modals. In the JavaScript function I am getting that value. Now how can I pass the `runstatus` value to modal to display it.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your variable value directly to the modal, create a container in it, and put your variable in it, after you show modal(or before it), like that:

```
$('#status').modal('show');
$('#container').text(runstatus);
```

Comment: How to access the runStatus inside the modal?

Comment: You want to pass runStatus as a parameter to the modal function?

Comment: I need to fetch the value from js and access that value inside the modal function to display in UI.

Comment: You can use data-attributes to the link, for that